# Why can I not write over a cookie using jQuery.cookie plugin?

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
alert('You clicked: '+this.currentSortCol);
$.cookie('#'+this.settings.table+'-sortCol',this.currentSortCol);
alert('The cookie is: '+$.cookie('#'+this.settings.table+'-sortCol'));
```

This block of code worked one time and initially set the cookie. Now, it will not set the cookie. The first alert box properly displays the value of the column I clicked on, and the second alert box still displays the value of another column.

Comment: Are you sure the domain is the same?

Comment: Yes; the second line of code I posted is exactly the line of code that set the cookie in the first place. It just won't set it again.

Comment: Yes, but does this run in the same exact page, or is it running on multiple pages in different directories?

Comment: try to unset then reset the cookie. 
`alert('You clicked: '+this.currentSortCol);
$.cookie('#'+this.settings.table+'-sortCol',null);
$.cookie('#'+this.settings.table+'-sortCol',this.currentSortCol);
alert('The cookie is: '+$.cookie('#'+this.settings.table+'-sortCol'));`

Comment: @zzzzBov This script runs in the same exact page.

Comment: Are you sure that cookie values are dynamically updated and available to the jQuery cookie plugin? Seems to me you would need to refresh the page before you could access the updated cookie value.

Comment: Even if that were the case, refreshing the page gives the same result.

Comment: And how about if you delete, then re-set the cookie. Similar to McMaster above, but explicitly use the plugin's remove functionality: `$.removeCookie('#' + this.settings.table + '-sortCol');`

Comment: I tried that, but realized I was using a version that does not support that method. I went into my browser settings just now and saw that the cookie was set twice: once for '/' and once for '/projects'. I don't know how that could happen; the default behavior is supposed to be the current page and not the whole domain. Deleting the cookies fixed it.

Comment: bizarre! well, at least it's resolved. I would update your initialize code to explicitly set the `domain` and `path` options. Make sure to answer your own question with that answer to help others! :)